# Determining convergence with taking the limit of a function greater than it

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

Why does the Sandwhich Theorem have to be used here? Why couldn't we just test for the result of the right side of the inequality and say that $a_n$ converges, since the function greater than itself converges?

[image]

Comment: Of course a sandwich is required. If you had lettuce and put bread only on the above, then the lettuce would fall down, right? Similarly, if you bound a function only from the top, there's absolutely no guarantee of how far below it's going to go. For example, if you take $f(x) = -10^{10^x}$, then of course you know that $f(x) < 1$ for all $x$, so there is a bounding function on the top. However, you can't find a nice bounding function  on the bottom, and that's because $f(x)$ absolutely steams towards $-\infty$ as $x\to \infty$. I hope you have understood. If not, do ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have confused with this correct theorem (called comparison test):

If $\sum b_n$ converges and $0\leq a_n\leq b_n$ then $\sum a_n$ also converges.

---

What you mentioned: " $a_n$ converges, if the function greater than itself converges" is not correct:

Example: $a_n=(-1)^n\leq 2$, and 2 being a constant sequence surely converges, but $a_n$ does not converge.